# Three upgradeable access level in joomla 2,5

Tags: authentication, joomla, user-registration

i want to register diffrent level of users in my joomla site, i've installed also CB(community builder). now i would like to register 3 types of users in my site in three level,  mean guest(default users), newsletter, limited user(testers), club user(real members).
actually the problem is there is not a simple way to let users upgrade their accounts.
so the question :" how can we create a hierarchy level users access in a upgradeable way? "

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Akeeba Subscriptions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce/membership-a-subscriptions/19528). This will allow you to create 3 different subscription levels and depending on which one they choose, add them to a specific user group. This component also allow users to upgrade their subscription which in your case, would be to upgrade to a different user group.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks a lot! :) but for further requirements i had to choose another solution, now i am using the CB-subs, its a complete module and helps me to resolve also the payments task at the same time, and obviously it will work fine also with the main CB component.